# IOS xcode 11.7 error running flutter build ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

While running flutter build ios on Xcode 11.7 I faced this error ios pod target-derived data permission denied.image attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOx2v.png)

Comment: First try running `flutter clean` in the terminal, and if that doesn't work I'll do a bit more digging for you.

Comment: check your development certificate on keychain access. It should be marked as valid